# Entity Framework Count Parent rows that have a child record with a constraint

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a parent and child table.  It is a one to many relationship.
I am trying to determine a way to count the number of parent records that have a child record with a constraint on both the child and parent.

Example:
Count the number of parent records that were created today and have a child record that with a value of true in in the address column.

I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from p in context.Parents
where p.CreatedOn.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
&& p.Children.Any(c=>c.Address != null) // or p.Children.Any(c=>c.Address == true)
select p).Count()
```

May be something like this?

You can also go from the children, for example:

```
(from c in context.Child
where c.Address == true && c.Parent.CreatedOn.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
select c.Parent).Distinct().Count()
```

In lambda expression, please note that I just used childObj.Address == true (most likely that condition is a bit different, but you should see the idea.

```
  context.ARC_Records
                      .Where(d => (d.Signed == false || d.Signed == null) 
                            && d.ChildObject.Any(c=>c.Address == true))
                     .Count();
```

Comment: I am using a different method of querying.  Not sure what it is called. count = context.ARC_Records.Where(d => ((d.Signed == false) || (d.Signed == null))).Count();  Not sure how to use what you posted

Comment: @SteveS perhaps post some code then so we can see how you want to do this, AD.Nets answer looks pretty good to me

Comment: Example of how I am normally querying with EF   count = context.ARC_Records.Where(d => ((d.Signed == false) || (d.Signed == null))).Count();

Comment: That's called lambda expression, I wrote it in this fashion so that it's a bit more readable and clearer.

Comment: Not sure how to convert your code to lambda expression, sorry I am new at this